# MVC send dropdown value to databse and post it in table

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi i am new in mvc and I'm trying to send my dropdown value to database and post it to table, any suggest best way how it will work ? .. thanks in advance

ContactController.cs

```
public ActionResult Create()
{

    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

     items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "English", Value = "0", Selected = true });

     items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "German", Value = "1" });

     items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Spanish", Value = "2"});

     items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Italian", Value = "3" });

     ViewBag.LanguageList = items;

    return View();
}
```

---

Create.cshtml

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.language)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.language, new SelectList(ViewBag.LanguageList))
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.language)
</div>
```

---

Index.cshtml

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.language)
</td>
```

Comment: Did my post help you?

Comment: If you could accept the answer that would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, put your Dropdown selection in a form with a submit button:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ContactController", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
      {
          @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
          <div class="editor-label">

          @Html.LabelFor(model => model.language)
          </div>
          <div class="editor-field">
          @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.language, new SelectList(ViewBag.LanguageList))
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.language)
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Enable" class="btn btn-link" />      
      }
```

Controller:

```
//This action can only be accessed with the Http.Post verb
[HttpPost]
//Validate the antiforgerytoken we set with `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in the view (Prevents CSRF attacks)
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(YourModel model)
{

//Your model will now contain the value of the selected dropdown if you have wired up your model correctly.

//Connect to db, persist model.language

    return View();
}
```